# Answer reposting for close (but not duplicate) questions

Tags: discussion

Recently, there was a question posted that was very similar to another question, but it was not close enough to be considered as a duplicate. [This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/13635/638) is very similar to [this one that I answered](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/7042/638).

Duplicate issues aside, I feel that I could copy and paste the old answer as an answer to the new question, and it would be a good answer. Joby Taffey linked to the original question, and I've seen a reputation boost from new people seeing the old question and answer.

What I'm looking for is the StackExchange-ish way of handling this situation. I'm not very interested in re-writing my answer (I've already done the work once), and just copying/linking the old answer or a paragraph from the old answer seems like it doesn't really add anything to the site.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that the two questions were linked. But, they didn't seem close enough to merge

Comment: @Joby, And that's fine, I don't disagree - I think it's a toss-up between closing and keeping the question. I'm not interested in that, but in how to provide an answer in the future that is essentially a duplicate answer.

Comment: I think it could be closed as duplicated and linked to master question. So your answer will be valid for both. I have to confirm this.

Comment: Anyhow, I think it should be closed as too localized

Answer (score 2):

*Whenever* you can take a non-trivial answer from one question to another, without changing it, and have it answer both completely... There's a pretty good chance one should be closed as a duplicate of the other.

But if they're *really* not duplicates (and honestly, I could go either way on this; but "what company am I thinking of" is sort of a lousy question, so you kinda have to reinterpret it a bit anyway), and there's no good, respectful way to generalize one or both such that they *become* duplicates, consider posting an answer to the new one that addresses whatever aspects make it distinct and then *link to your answer on the original question*.

> I don't know the name of the specific company you're linking to, but I've [elsewhere posted information on companies that do just what you're describing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7042/how-much-does-it-cost-to-have-a-custom-asic-made/7051#7051) that you should find useful.